# python read only integers from file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't figure the way to read from this file, only the integers:

```
34
-1
2 48
  +0
++2
+1
 2.4
1000
-0
three
-1
```

The function should return:

```
[34, -1, 0, 1, -1]
```

If a number has `+` or `-` is valid. But if it has `++` or any letters is not.

If it has a space (as for example `2 48` ) is not valid.

If it is > 999 it is not valid.

I am stuck only at here:

```
my_list = []
with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        my_list.append(line.strip())
```

I tried to make it a string and use punctuation using `translate` but I am not sure if it gets more complicated.

Also, I am not sure about using regex. I tried a simple regex but I don't have experience using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wanted to do this via regular expressions:

```
import re
exp = re.compile(r'^[\+,\-]?[0-9]{1,3}$')

my_list = []
with open('input.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if re.match(exp, line.strip()):
            my_list.append(int(line.strip()))
```

Lets explain the regular expressions.

`^[\+,\-]?` - `^` means the expression must start with the next qualifiers, which are a list of two characters `\+` and `\-`. We need the escaping slashes there to actually put in the special chars in. The final `?` makes the preceding argument optional (so the string can start with a + or -, or nothing).

`[0-9]{1,3}$` - `[0-9]` specifies the set of characters that are numbers. `{1,3}` specifies that they should occur a minimum of one time, or a max of 3 times (hence satisfying your `<999` constraint. The `$` sign matches the end of the string, so the string must end with this set of chars.

Hope this all helps.

Comment: As with all regular expressions, better make it a raw string: `r"...."`. In Python 3.6 the `\+` is deprecated if you don't specify it as raw string. But a very good solution and explanation (+1)

Comment: Thanks @MSeifert, have edited the answer to make it a raw string for completeness.

Answer (score 8):

You can convert string to integer using `int()`. It will throw `ValueError` if string is not integer. So try this:

```
my_list = []
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            n = int(line)
            if n > 999 or line.strip() == '-0':
                #filtering numbers >999 and strings with '-0' 
                continue 
            my_list.append(n)
        except ValueError:
            pass

print(my_list)
```

Output: `[34, -1, 0, 1, -1]`

Comment: It appears from the question that `-0` should also be invalid. In that case, replace the if statement with this: `if n > 999 or (n == 0 and '-' in line): continue`

Comment: Thanks.Upvoted.I am copying from the other answer also my question.I can't understand though , if I use only val = int(line.strip()) without exception control, it throws me invalid literal for int() with base 10.Here, you use continue if it encounters an error.But, how it continues since the error exists?

Comment: @George If `ValueError` occurs (`line` is not an integer) it jumps to `except` statement (where it does not add value to `my_list`). And when you have `"-0"` it is not `ValueError` (`int("-0")` is just `0`), so I check it manually.

Comment: Oh,yes!You are right!My fault , I din't see that it doesn't add it.Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it by hand (note that a `regex` solution or calling `int` are probably more suitable but these are already covered in other answers) then you can also implement each check by yourself:

```
import string

characters_and_whitspaces = set(string.ascii_letters + ' .')

mylist = []

for line in lines:
    # remove leading and trailing whitespaces
    val = line.strip()

    # Check if valid (!= -0)
    if val == '-0':
        continue
    # Must not start with ++, +-, ....
    if val.startswith(('++', '+-', '-+', '--')):
        continue
    # Must not contain letters or whitespaces or a dot
    if characters_and_whitspaces.intersection(val):
        continue
    # Must only contain 3 or less digits (<= 999) or 4 if it starts with + or -
    if val.startswith(('+', '-')):
        if len(val) >= 5):
            continue
    elif len(val) >= 4:
        continue

    # Remove leading "+"
    val = val.lstrip('+')

    mylist.append(val)
```

Comment: Just a note this doesn't catch all cases, from my reading `+999` should be accepted but doesn't pass your checks. Maybe a check such as `if int(val) > 999` instead?

Comment: @Gavin I tried to avoid the `int`-conversion in this answer but you are definitly right and I've edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a regexp solution:

```
import re

rgx = re.compile(r'^\s*[-+]?\s*(?:0|0*\d{1,3})\s*$', re.M)

with open('test.txt') as f:
    my_list = [int(match) for match in rgx.findall(f.read())]
```

Output:

```
[34, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think regex is the way to go for you. You can achieve what you want with somethin like this: `[-+]?\d*`It looks for a + or -, the question mark means optional and then for an arbitrary number of digits.
An easy way to find the right regex for your case is https://regex101.com/. You can directly see what is matched by your regex and it is explained to you. In python, regular exressions can be used by the re module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Hope this helps you.